# Idiomatic way to transform a growing vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pipeline, idioms

Say I have a vector in Clojure:

```
(def myvec (atom (vector 1)))
```

And I have this function that adds new values to the vector:

```
(defn inc-myvec! []
  (swap! myvec conj (inc (last @myvec))))
```

Assume that this function gets called from time to time on some trigger. Let's trigger it a few times.

```
(dotimes [i 5] (inc-myvec!))
@myvec
;=> [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Now, if I want to subtract 1 from every element in that vector I would do something like this:

```
(def myvec2 (atom (mapv dec @myvec)))
@myvec2
;=> [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

This is of course not great as I have to do this on every change of myvec. It is also wasteful as it does the whole vector on every change. We can do better. Let's implement observer pattern and calculate only the last value which gets appended:

```
(defn watcher [_ _ _ new-myvec]
  (swap! myvec2 conj (dec (last new-myvec))))
(add-watch myvec :watcher watcher)
```

This is not bad. But ideally I'd want the watcher to operate in another thread for starters. Are there are better, more idiomatic ways of dealing with this kind of transformations where you basically need to react to incoming data stream as it arrives and transform it into something else?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to improve here. Can you formulate the general use case? there are libraries for manipulating streams, but your example is hardly about streams IMHO(why vectors, and why the atoms?). If I was to optimize your example, I'd do it with a custom "range" data structure (which is as lightweight as a 2-tuple of ints).

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck General use case would be calculating one vector based on another. Vectors are not important part of example, could be maps or lists. I'm using addition and subtraction, but in real life those would be relatively intensive calculations. I'd therefore like to have second operation in another thread (which is the reason I'm using atoms), and with watches it's not possible (though I can fork a future inside watch). I'm not sure what bothers me with this; I guess I'm OK with people telling me that this is OK, but somehow I expect to hear "no silly it's not how it's done." :)

Comment: Is the general use case really about calculating a whole collection based on a whole other collection ? (very un-stream-like) Because in your last refinement you seem OK with being up to date only for the last value. Sorry to insist but oftentimes the answer lies in a better formulation of the question :)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck - of course! Input collections I'm dealing with are endless, with readings that come in relatively fast, up to a couple of times a sec. Output collection is based on input values, but in some period (not less than one value per minute). Idea is to calculate output as input comes in. My example where I calculate the whole thing is just a starting point, last example is more what I'm looking for. I'm using up to a few values from tail of a collection or just last value in input for calculation of a latest value in output.

Comment: that's definitely streams - check out core async and get rid of those atoms :)

Comment: Will do - thanks @ValentinWaeselynck!

Answer (score 3):

If you explained the general use case a bit more, it might be easier to point you in the right direction. Do you truly need a vector as the output (i.e random access capabilities)? Or do you just want a way to transform data from one source and put it elsewhere?

If you don't actually need the random access of the vector I would say using [core.async](http:///https://github.com/clojure/core.async) and channels is the best way to do this. This way you can have specific threads or go loops handling each step of the data publishing, transformation, and consumption solely by placing a channel in between them.

Here are a few good articles to learn about core.async from (but there are many more out there if you do a quick google):

- http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/
- http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html
- https://tbaldridge.pivotshare.com/ - Check out the core.async specific videos. They're awesome and go really in depth.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I do not necessarily need vectors; depending on the data and the particular case my collections will actually more likely be maps or lists. But I'm in all cases looking only at tail values so channels are very much relevant and I'm definitely considering them.